# Multicolumn listbox - Add item: Invalid or unqualified reference

Tags: excel, vba, reference, listbox

i need your assistance.
Trying to populate a userform listbox with values to be selected later..

But i am struggling with the listbox, when i do a msgbox for debug it works great, but when i try to additem it fails, please advice where i made a mistake..

```
' Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim MyRows As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = Sheets("Data2020")
sh.Select

Me.PendingList.ColumnCount = 3
Me.PendingList.ColumnWidths = "50;50"
i = 1

rowCount = sh.Range("Y1", sh.Range("Y1").End(xlDown)).rows.Count

While Me.PendingList
    For MyRows = 1 To rowCount
        If sh.Cells(MyRows, 25) = 0 Then
            ' MsgBox ("" & MyRows & " " & sh.Cells(MyRows, 2).Value)  WORKS..

            .AddItem

' Testing with numbers, incase its the sheet that is failing me.
            .List(i, 0) = MyRows ' sh.Cells(MyRows, 1).Value
            .List(i, 1) = MyRows + 1 ' sh.Cells(MyRows, 2).Value

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next MyRows
Wend

Unload OpenPending
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `AddItem`, you specify the first column on the call, and then the rest of the columns later:

```
        .AddItem sh.Cells(MyRows, 1).Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) =  sh.Cells(MyRows, 2).Value
```